# Different interface design with different iPhone device

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface-builder

When I run my app on an iPhone with a 3.5-inch screen and then on a 4-inch screen, the position of things in the interface will move automatically. Is there any way to change position of each thing in the interface for different devices manually so everything is where I want it?

For example:

iPhone 3.5" (Cropped):
[image]

iPhone 4.0" (Cropped):
[image]

I don't like that the label moves to the bottom on the 4 inch screen. I want to move the image view a little bit nearer the label.

Is there any way to modify this the way I want?

Comment: Are you using a xib/storyboard or are you creating your views in code?  Are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Autolayout for Storeyboard and set position manually or use Struts and springs

Answer (score 1):

Disabling autolayout or spring and struts won't help you, but using autolayout or springs and struts correctly will help you, by using them correctly you will have the desired results even if Apple decides to create an even "longer" device.